# Firebug's :hover state not triggering

Tags: hover, firebug

I am using Firefox 28.0 and the newest Firebug for 28. When I hover over a menu button I click the Style panel tab and choose *:hover* from the options, but it does not lock into hover state. In fact it does nothing. I have tried variations of using *:active* and clicking *Only Show Applied Styles* but nothing.

I am sure this is some simple thing going on here, but it's really annoying not being able to use *:hover*, despite it being selected.

Comment: Maybe you're setting the hover state on the wrong element? Could you please add some example code and tell where exactly you set that state. Also what is "the newest Firebug"? The current stable version is 1.12.7.

Comment: Here is the code I am attempting to change but it goes away as I move my mouse, even with hover and/or focus selected: 
 .primary-navigation li:hover > a, .primary-navigation li.focus > a {
    background-color: #24890D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
Further, I see in the code on this element I am attempting to inspect (this is word press child/parent) 
 *::-moz-selection {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #24890D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
Declared twice, once much later, so even when I change this, it appears to get overwritten by the parent.  Thanks for any help

Comment: Note that you can edit your question. Please put your CSS **and** HTML there or a link to a page, where the issue can be reproduced.